# AngularJS controller not executing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

This is the core content of my index.html file:

```
<div role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top navbar-inverse " data-ng-contoller="NavController">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button data-target=".navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle" type="button">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Bootstrap theme</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li ng-class="{active: isHome()}"><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#/editor">New Message</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">List Messages</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>



    <div data-ng-view="" id="main-container" class="container" role="main"></div>
```

This is how my app is bootstrapped:

```
define(['app', 'jquery', 'bootstrap', 'angular' ], function(app, jQuery, bootstrap, angular) {
    jQuery('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
    require(['domReady!'], function (document) {
         angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
    });
});
```

All of the other controllers work just fine. The only thing I can guess is that for some reason it's being ignored by the bootstrap.

All of the dependencies are loaded with requirejs, and I can see that the code is loaded fine with no errors in the console (including the controller that doesn't work). Any ideas on how to track this down?

Comment: where is controller function? show NavController code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a typo. I had `contoller` not `controller`.